# Error when trying to move the robot via python script

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I wrote a little python script to test moving the robot around in Gazebo, in which the robot just rotates around it z axis 5s clockwise and after that 5s counter clockwise in an while loop.

When i started my python script via rosrun move_pepper move_pepper.py i got following error:

pub = rospy.publisher('/pepper/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'publisher'

I dont really know what this means and i followed a tutorial in which very thing is the same

Here is my script code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

import rospy

from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

from time import sleep

rospy.init_node('movep')

pub = rospy.publisher('/pepper/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)

rotate_right = True

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
msg = Twist()
msg.angular.z = 0.1 if rotate_right else -0.1

```
pub.publish(msg)

rotate_right = not rotate_right

sleep(5)
```

what do i need to do to get it running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363835/error-when-trying-to-move-the-robot-via-python-script/) by [Qilos](https://answers.ros.org/users/60189/qilos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2020-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qilos](https://answers.ros.org/users/60189/qilos/) on 2020-10-20**:
i also dont know why it didnt properly show my code here, just the first and the last 3 lines

**Comment by [RobertZickler](https://answers.ros.org/users/52301/robertzickler/) on 2020-10-20**:
This has to do with indentation of the text. Try to indent with 5 times 'space'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to write rospy.Publisher(...). With a capital P

Like described here: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers

Robert

---

Originally posted by [RobertZickler](https://answers.ros.org/users/52301/robertzickler/) with karma: 104 on 2020-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qilos](https://answers.ros.org/users/60189/qilos/) on 2020-10-20**:
Thank you very much that was the culprit